# How to monitor whether a file was created?

Tags: files, monitoring, inotify

I need to monitor if, for example, file **/tmp/somefile123** was created after some events. I tried to use **inotifywait** but here is a problem:

```
# inotifywait -q -e create /tmp/somefile?*
Couldn't watch /tmp/somefile?*: No such file or directory
```

because there is exactly no such file, I want to know if it will be there!

How can I resolve this issue?

**UPD**: Maybe if I explain what I want to reach it will be more clear.

I need to write shell script (sh) with minimal CPU consumption, something like this:

```
if [ $(inotifywait -e create $SPECIFIC_FILE) ]; then
    blah-blah-blah some actions
fi
# And then similarly monitor if this file was deleted and then do another actions
```

I expect that script will stop execution on **inotifywait -e create $SPECIFIC_FILE** till this $SPECIFIC_FILE will not created and it would be better then

```
while [ ! -f $SPECIFIC_FILE ]; do
    blah-blah-blah some actions
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By having *inotifywait* check on the *parent directory*:

```
/tmp$ inotifywait -e create -d -o /home/me/zz /tmp
/tmp$ touch z1
/tmp$ cat ~/zz
/tmp/ CREATE z1
```

You can also specify the time format for the event with the *-timefmt* option. Also, if you want to act immediately by executing some script file, for instance, you may use *tail -f* in the script file to monitor continuously the log file, here */home/me/zz*, or you can create a *named pipe* file and have *inotifywait* write to it, while your script reads from it.

Comment: Maybe I didn't write clearly enough what I want to reach. I edited my question

Comment: @HeroFromEarth I am sorry, but my answer above fits exactly what you stated in your OP and your update. Why do you believe it does not?

Comment: I misunderstood your answer at first, sorry. Is making log file and reading it with `tailf | grep 'pattern'` will do less CPU consumption then while loop?

Comment: Mark your answer as accepted because this is right, but question about "what better" still open :)